# Basic data frame analysis in r

Tags: r

I am brand new to R and my rather trivial question revolves around a data frame with two variables: salary and gender and several thousand entries. What I want to do isolate the data so I can perform basic statistical operations with respect to salary BUT for each gender to specifically. I know there must exist some simple operation to do this but I cannot seem to find to find the proper functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please include a reproducible example, and more details (what 'simple operation'?)
Here are some examples.

```
mydata <- data.frame(salary=runif(50,100,200),
    gender=as.factor(rep(c("male","female"),each=25)))
with(mydata, tapply(salary, gender, mean))

library(doBy)
summaryBy(salary ~ gender, FUN=c(mean,sd,min,max), data=mydata)
```

Comment: Thank you so much I know my question made very little sense but you answered exactly was I hoping for. I didn't quite understand the "tapply()" function with respect to data frame but you managed to give it some context for me without even understanding what I was asking. Thank you so much !

Comment: @user2680851, what you're doing is "aggregating" your data. As such, another simple option is `aggregate(salary ~ gender, mydata, mean)`.

Comment: @user2680851: There is nothing to understand about using `tapply` with dataframes. The first argument to `tapply` is atomic. Dataframes are recursive. The `with` function creates a local environment where the column names of a dataframe get evaluated. So one atomic vector, one factor vector, and a function got passed to`tapply` in the example above.

Comment: What if I wanted to add a third variable, say education level with 4 levels 1=bachelors, 2=masters, 3=doctorate,4=professional. How could I calculate mean,median,stander deviation etc., of the salary for each gender IN each education level?

Comment: then you could do, `summaryBy(salary ~ gender+education, FUN=c(mean,sd,min,max), data=mydata)`

Answer (score 1):

A third option, which I like a lot, is the `plyr` package. This breaks data frames (or lists or arrays) into pieces based on the value of one of the columns of the data frame. You can then perform whatever operation you like on the data frame. This is called the 'split-apply-combine' strategy for data analysis. For instance, if you wanted the mean and standard deviation of your `data` column for each unique combination of salary and gender, you would do something like

```
#load the package
require(plyr)

#make up some fake data
gender <- gl(2, 1, 100, labels=c("m", "f"))
# Note that I'm assuming salary will be a categorical variable
salary <- gl(5, 1, 100, labels=c("very low", "low", "medium", "high", "very high"))
data <- runif(100)

df <- data.frame(gender=gender, salary=salary, data=data)

# Calculate the mean for each combination of gender and salary
meanAndSD <- ddply(df, c("gender", "salary"), summarise, meanData=mean(data), sdData=sd(data))
print(meanAndSD)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's often several ways to do the same task in R.  Another one is to use the `by` function.  Following on from Remko's example:

```
mydata <- data.frame(salary=runif(50,100,200),
    gender=as.factor(rep(c("male","female"),each=25)))
by(mydata,mydata$gender,function(x) mean(x$salary))
```